# TicTacToe game code

Tags: python

I'm trying to code Tic Tac Toe where computer plays randomly with itself. But the output that I get is not realistic.

I mean sometimes I get this for example:

X X X

O O O

X O X

Which Is not possible in real. My question is: How can I avoid that kind of situations?

Here is my code:

```
import random

a = random.randrange(0,2)
if a==0:
    a = 'O'
else:
    a = 'X'

b = random.randrange(0,2)
if b==0:
    b = 'O'
else:
    b = 'X'

c = random.randrange(0,2)
if c==0:
    c = 'O'
else:
    c = 'X'

d = random.randrange(0,2)
if d==0:
    d = 'O'
else:
    d = 'X'

e = random.randrange(0,2)
if e==0:
    e = 'O'
else:
    e = 'X'

f = random.randrange(0,2)
if f==0:
    f = 'O'
else:
    f = 'X'

g = random.randrange(0,2)
if g==0:
    g = 'O'
else:
    g = 'X'

h = random.randrange(0,2)
if h==0:
    h = 'O'
else:
    h = 'X'

i = random.randrange(0,2)
if i==0:
    i = 'O'
else:
    i = 'X'


Win_Combination = (
    (a, b, c), (d, e, f), (g, h, i),   #Win Horizontal
     (a, d, g), (b, e, h), (c, f, i),  #Win vertical
     (a, e, i), (c, e, g))             #Win diagonal


print(a, b, c)
print(d, e, f)
print(g, h, i)
print()

if a == b and b ==  c:
    print ('Win')
    exit 
elif d == e and e == f:
    print ('Win')
    exit
elif g == h and h == i:
    print ('Win')
    exit
elif a == d and d == g: 
    print ('Win')
    exit
elif b == e and e == h:
    print ('Win')
    exit
elif c == f and f == i:
    print ('Win')
    exit
elif a == e and e == i:
    print ('Win')
    exit
elif c == e and e == g:
    print ('Win')
    exit
```

Comment: You're choosing the content of each cell independently. You will have to implement an algorithm to handle the logic of the game.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean?

Comment: I mean you don't simulate a poker match by dropping the deck on the floor.

Comment: i'm new to programming and I have to do this for school. I know it's very basic what I did here. But is there a simple way that I can avoid that kind of situation?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 [Bogo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort)poker!

Comment: For each move of the game, you have to select (at random) one of the _possible_ valid next moves.  Repeat this (alternating sides, of course) until there are no more valid next moves. At this point, the game ends.

Comment: Just by the way here, but using an actual algorithm can make your program not only clearer and more realistic, but also _shorter_. For example, [this](https://github.com/TigerhawkT3/small_scripts/blob/master/ttt.py) (disclosure: I wrote it) is 27 lines, while your current code is 92 lines.

Comment: at line 15 there is an error. "unindent does not match any outer indentation level".

Comment: sorry. it was my mistake I didn't copy paste well

Comment: but when I execute your program there is nothing??

Comment: and by the way you're code is way to much advanced for me xD i'm just a beginner haha

Comment: There is "nothing" (other than an input prompt of `> `) because it's for two players; it won't produce a result automatically.

Comment: what i'm suppose to make is that the computer should play all by itself randomly.

Comment: Start planning out an algorithm, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this doesn't have any robust move selection, and follows the random position choice, the code below should fulfill the game requirements using numpy and random.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import pandas as pd

def convertarray(arr):
    """
    Convert numpy array into desired format of X's and O's
    :param arr: numpy array
    :return: convert matrix
    """
    df = pd.DataFrame(arr).replace({1.0: 'X', 2.0: 'O', 0: ''}, inplace=False)
    return df


########################
# Set Game Variables

# Set game board
a = np.zeros([3,3])

# Set values
X = 1
O = 2

# all available remaining positions on the board
positions = list(range(0,9))
turn = [X,O]

# store string representation of board pieces for game over
turndict = {1: 'X', 2: 'O'}

quitgame = 1
#########################

while quitgame != 10:

    # if no available positions left, quit game
    if len(positions) == 0:
        quitgame = 10
        break

    # choose random position
    tmppos = random.choice(positions)

    # remove available position
    positions.remove(tmppos)

    # assign value of position to board
    a = a.reshape([9,1])
    a[tmppos] = turn[0]
    a = a.reshape([3,3])

    # slide over rows and columns to determine if winner present
    toview = range(0,3)
    for index in toview:
        # sum the column values
        column = np.sum(a[:,index])
        # sum the row values
        row = np.sum(a[index, :])
        # if remainder of division of 3 is zero and no non zero elements occur
        # game is over
        if row % 3 == 0 and np.count_nonzero(a[index,:]) == 3:
            print('Game over, {} wins!'.format(turndict[turn[0]]))
            print(convertarray(a))
            quitgame = 10
            break
        elif column % 3 == 0 and np.count_nonzero(a[:, index]) == 3:
            print('Game over, {} wins!'.format(turndict[turn[0]]))
            print(convertarray(a))
            quitgame = 10
            break


    # see if diagonals win
    if a.trace() % 3 == 0 and np.count_nonzero(a.diagonal()) == 3:
        print('Game over, {} wins!'.format(turndict[turn[0]]))
        print(convertarray(a))
        quitgame = 10
        break
    elif np.fliplr(a).trace() % 3 == 0 and np.count_nonzero(np.fliplr(a).diagonal()) == 3:
        print('Game over, {} wins!'.format(turndict[turn[0]]))
        print(convertarray(a))
        quitgame = 10
        break

    # reverse order of turn and repeat
    turn = list(reversed(turn))
```

If you really wanted to do some neat things with the game logic, you could train a simple classifier to pick the next best move. There is training data available that would get you close to the right set up to do this https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Tic-Tac-Toe+Endgame and research exploring the accuracy of using this approach across a number of classifiers http://www.ijiet.org/papers/314-k010.pdf

Comment: for  positions.remove(tmppos)
 it says : 'range' object has no attribute 'remove'. What does that mean?

Comment: I know this is not quite related, but here comes Twitter compatible Tic Tac Toe ;) main(){int a,b;char c[]="...\n...\n...",*d;h:scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);a=b+4*a;if(c[a]=='.'){c[a]=88;d=strchr(c,46);d?*d=79:0;}puts(c);goto h;}

Comment: thanks datawrestler. But the output are number 1 or 2 instead of X and O

Comment: @gulraizsafdar you should have the desired output now - you could turn this into a function quite easily and then set the number of games to be played and keep tally of who does better. You could also use the classifier mentioned above and see how much better a smarter system does than random.